# Viewport width=device-width, initial-scale=1 not giving me full width

Tags: html, css, viewport, meta

I have this meta tag on a website `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`. It works on my desktop however it's not giving me the full width in mobile. Both my html and my body tags have 100% width.

[Link to the site](http://carlosbergen.com/vidabundante)

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: @Ferrrmolina Added a link to the site

Comment: In `#mobile-menu-container` you use `width: 100vw`. In iOs this cause some problems. Look this link: https://gist.github.com/pburtchaell/e702f441ba9b3f76f587

Comment: @Ferrrmolina I've updated the css to use width:100% but still no luck

Comment: Ok, the problem is this `<h1>`, maybe you need to use another font-sizes to fix that: http://prntscr.com/9r1tej

Comment: @Ferrrmolina, thanks! That worked. Do you want to put it as the answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this `<h1>`, maybe you need to use another font-size to fix that:

[image]